# how to calculate based on index?

Tags: python, indexing, grouping, calculation

i have brunch of raw data in excel,
column=company code,date(1year daily data),closing price,...
will sort by company code and date
it have around 900++ company in the list
I import data to python and try to calculate brunch of calculation,
for example I need first difference of closing price,
data["first difference"]=data[closing price]-data[closing price].shift()
but the question is when change to next company, the difference will be calculated last day of first company data and the first day of company data, so I need a code to separate the company to calculate to data
how to do it using python?
i how you all can understand my description, thanks!

Comment: Your description is pretty difficult to understand. Please include your data, your expected output and your current solution in the post. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already use it, I would suggest the pandas library. It can read your comma separated data to a DataFrame, and from there you can do a bunch of things, such as only looking at one company at a time.
Importing looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')
df
...
```

From there it depends on exactly what you want to achieve :)
It sounds like you might need loc(), groupby(), and general indexing etc.